# GMaps JavaScript API: How to determine the screen position of markers/objects

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to implement a function to snap in markers if hovered and if they are close to each other.
For this I need to read the location of the window and not the geo coordinates. 
How is this possible?

Comment: Check `google.maps.Projection` object method `fromLatLngToPoint()`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that:

```
  /**
  * @param {google.maps.Map} map
  * @param {google.maps.LatLng} latlng
  * @param {int} z
  * @return {google.maps.Point}
  */
  var latlngToPoint = function(map, latlng, z){
    var normalizedPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng); // returns x,y normalized to 0~255
    var scale = Math.pow(2, z);
    var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(normalizedPoint.x * scale, normalizedPoint.y * scale);

    //console.log('Position: ' + pixelCoordinate.x + "; " + pixelCoordinate.y);
    return pixelCoordinate; 
  };
```